# Angular Material Table: "Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'table'"

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular17

I'm trying to add a table in my Angular app from Angular Material@17.2.1 (as shown [here](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview)).

I copy / pasted the code from the Angular Material official documentation but I still get the error:

> Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'table'

I tried the following:

Replacing table tag with mat-table, resulting in

> mat-table is not a known element

Deleting the brackets in `[dataSource]="dataSource"` as `dataSource="dataSource"`, resulting in (Webdeveloper console error this time, this could be the solution but I don't know how to fix it even after some searches)

> Can't bind to 'matHeaderRowDef' since it isn't a known property of 'tr' (used in the '_UsersComponent' component template).

importing `MatTableModule` from `'@angular/material'` instead of `'@angular/material/table'` in `app.module.ts`, resulting in

> @angular/material has no expôrted member MatTableModule

Add `import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';` and importing it, changing nothing.

The `MatTableModule` is declared and imported in `app.module.ts`, where the `UsersComponent` using it is also declared and imported.

Here are all versions used in the project:

@angular-devkit/architect       0.1702.2

@angular-devkit/build-angular   17.2.2

@angular-devkit/core            17.2.2

@angular-devkit/schematics      17.2.2

@angular/cdk                    17.2.1

@angular/cli                    17.2.2

@angular/material               17.2.1

@schematics/angular             17.2.2

rxjs                            7.8.1

typescript                      5.3.3

zone.js                         0.14.4

Here is my `app.module.ts` file's content:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TopbarComponent } from './topbar/topbar.component';
import { LeftmenuComponent } from './leftmenu/leftmenu.component';
import { NavleftbarComponent } from './navleftbar/navleftbar.component';

import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';

import { provideAnimationsAsync } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations/async';
import { UsersComponent } from './users/users.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TopbarComponent,
    LeftmenuComponent,
    NavleftbarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatTableModule,
    UsersComponent,
    CdkTableModule
  ],
  providers: [
    provideAnimationsAsync()
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here's the `users.component.ts`'s file content:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';

export interface UserElement {
  firstname: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
  microsoftEmail: string;
  class: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: UserElement[] = [{
  firstname: "Pierrick",
  lastName: "MARTELLIERE",
  email: "p.martelliere@gmail.com",
  microsoftEmail: "pierrick@coxidev.com",
  class: "GPME24"
}];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrl: './users.component.css',
  standalone: true,
})

export class UsersComponent {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'microsoftEmail', 'class'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
  clickedRows = new Set<UserElement>();
}
```

And the users.component.html:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8 demo-table">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Prénom </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="lastName">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Email </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="microsoftEmail">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Compte Microsoft </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="class">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Classe </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>



<!-- Copyright 2024 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at https://angular.io/license -->
```

I really don't see what I am missing, some help would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component is a standalone component.

From your source:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrl: './users.component.css',
  standalone: true, // ---> Standalone!
})
```

Which means it is acting as its own module. You should import the MatTable here, isntead of your application Module.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrl: './users.component.css',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatTableModule], // ---> import done directly here!
})
```

Another option, is maybe you did not want a standalone component? Since I see it inside your imports of your AppModule. You then need simply to remove the `standlone:true` part in its declaration.

Comment: You might want to read more about standalone components here: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-standalone-components/

Comment: Thank you very much for spotting this incoherence, now the table is well displayed (there as much rows as objects in my dataSource, but each row is blank. Could you know what it come from ?
Thanks also for the related link about standalone components.

Comment: They are empty because you are displaying properties that are not in the UserElement interface.

Comment: Thanks again for everything ! I accepted your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

`UserElement` doesn’t have the properties:

```
{{element.position}} {{element.name}} {{element.weight}}
```

Change it to

```
{{element.firstName}} {{element.lastName}}
```

Comment: haha i think table in angular material is weird

Comment: Yeah this didn't even trigger an error on console nor shell...

Comment: Anyway this was not the answer to the question, but it caused the table to display blank rows so it helped me as well :) Thanks !